# What's the meaning of this query string

Tags: php, html, url

I have this directory of a PHP project, I am trying to locate the code according to the URL can anyone know where can I locate the section of the file below:

```
index.php?step=three
```

Comment: Guess #1: `index.php`.

Comment: What is this ?step=three?

Comment: That's a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). It's one way to supply additional information to your script so it can behave differently.

Comment: press CTRL/CMD + F (in most of editors) in file index.php, and find $_GET['step'] is getting compared with 'three'. For searching file index.php use your OS Search bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a URL:

```
index.php?step=three
```

Then the query string is:

```
step=three
```

In this case, the query consists: a key step with value three.

You can access the value of the query string keys using this code:

```
$id = $_GET['step'];
```

The above code gets the value of step, which is three.

Answer (score 1):

```
index.php?step=three

   $va= $_GET['step'];


 print $va;
```

your answer will be : three